# Please Help Identify These Star Wars Sets

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

I guess these are StarWars sets, please help to identify [image]

Answer (score 4):

1.Set# 75172 *[Y-Wing Starfighter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75172-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)*.

2.Set# 75013 *[Umbaran MHC (Mobile Heavy Cannon)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75013-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)*.

3.Set# 75003 *[A-Wing Starfighter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75003-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)*.

(Note: Canopy and gun turret on KETCHUP colored ship belongs on MUSTARD colored ship.)

See ya *Fabian*!
[image]
[image]
[image]